# Trouble with unsatisfied dependency when installing MySQL workbech

Tags: apt, mysql, dependencies

I am trying to instal MySQL workbech using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-worbench
```

But only thing i get is this:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3
                   Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
                   Depends: python2.7 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-mysql.connector but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-paramiko but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-pexpect but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: my version is 16.04

Comment: Okay, well apparently `libgdal1i` cannot be installed for some reason, so let's try to install it and see what happens: `LC_ALL=C sudo apt install libgdal1i`.

Comment: I believe the version of MySQL Workbench in the repositories causes some issues and doesn't work; have you tried downloading the MySQL Workbench Debian package from the MySQL website, and installed that?  Then run `apt-get install -f` afterwards?